# What is seed in RAND function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am not able to understand as to **what is the use of seed in the RAND** function of **SQL Server**?

I read the below link but i am not able to understand what it is doing?
[Link 1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fe04258e-d0d5-4608-8e77-f7ab3a48e7eb/seed-for-rand-function-in-sql-server-2005?forum=transactsql)
[Link 2](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_rand.asp)
[Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25872332/sql-server-random-using-seed)

After trying out few random seed number i found the below results:-

```
Select RAND(1) - 0.713591993212924
Select RAND(2) - 0.713610626184182
Select RAND(3) - 0.71362925915544
Select RAND(4) - 0.713647892126698
Select RAND(5) - 0.713666525097956
```

Whenever i provide the seed from **1 to 5** i always get the number that i have mentioned above.

Why is that so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft docs explains this in details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rand-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): apparently `RAND()` returns a really random result only if it is called without specifying a *seed* value (because in this case seed itself is assigned randonly).

So calling `RAND()` without seed should always return a different value, while calling `RAND(seed)` should always return the same result if called with the same seed.

Here is an excerpt from Microsoft docs:

> Arguments 
> seed 
> Is an integer expression (tinyint, smallint, or int)
>   that gives the seed value. If seed is not specified, the SQL Server
>   Database Engine assigns a seed value at random. For a specified seed
>   value, the result returned is always the same.
>
> Remarks 
>   **Repetitive calls of RAND() with the same seed value return the
>   same results.**